# OAuth: what to do if user refuses to share his data

Tags: php, oauth

I'm trying to implement OAuth login. After a user is redirected to login-provider and suggested to share his data, he can refuse. The question is where shall I be redirected and how do I know that user refused to share his data?

Comment: Why the question is closed as `too localized`? OAuth login is a common  thing, and a situation when a user refuses to share his data is common as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [OAuth 2.0 draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-30):

> **4.1.2.1. Error Response**
>
> If the request fails due to a missing, invalid, or mismatching
> redirection URI, or if the client identifier is missing or invalid,
> the authorization server SHOULD inform the resource owner of the
> error, and MUST NOT automatically redirect the user-agent to the
> invalid redirection URI.
>
> If the resource owner denies the access request or if the request
> fails for reasons other than a missing or invalid redirection URI,
> the authorization server informs the client by adding the following
> parameters to the query component of the redirection URI using the
> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format, per Appendix B:

The draft indicates what the error code will be depending on why the token was not granted.